# Can't Do File sharing and video chatting simultaneously in firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

Hi All I am currently working on WebRTC project. My case is where user can transfer file and do video/audio chatting simultaneously.

Consider the first scenario where user would like to transfer a file and the same time while transfer is in progress he/she needs to do video chatting. For this I have created a peer connection with data channel and this step completed successfully and am able to send the data to peer but issue arises when using same peer connection I am trying to do video chatting, although this **works fine in Chrome**, this **doesn't work in Firefox**.

In Firefox the user is able to add a video stream but can't get the remote video stream. I also fired getRemoteStreams on console but it doesn't get fired. If anyone have faced such issues or if anyone is aware of this please do help me on this.

Comment: Check https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc or refer to @Alon Gubkin.

Comment: As i have written code without using any third party library or their apis, i would appreciate the answers if it would be purely in WebRTC context or any samples or examples that demonstrate such requirement.

Comment: You will need two PeerConnections(I believe). Also, are both browsers FireFox or is just one FireFox and the other Chrome?

Comment: Individual peer connection might solve this issue but is this the only solution to the problem. By doing this every time I would be writing my code different for Firefox and chrome which becomes complex and messy. Since it's working fine in chrome, so is there something specific thing for Firefox.